# Why inherit from unittest.TestCase?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-3.x

What's the motivation behind having my unit test classes inherit from `unittest.TestCase`, rather than object`?` Does it matter if I'm using Nose (or PyTest) instead of `unittest`?

Comment: Because that's how `unittest` knows you want that class to be treated as a test case? *"Does it matter if I'm using Nose (or PyTest)"* - yes, they have other options for test discovery (although also accept `TestCase`s, see e.g. https://pytest.org/latest/unittest.html#unittest-testcase).

Comment: a) to inherit `assertX` methods? b) to allow automatic test runners to find your tests?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't inherit from `unit.TestCase`, the testing framework won't know that you want those classes to be test cases.  So when you try to *run* your tests, nothing will happen!

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting from [unittest.TestCase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) lets you use method like:

- [setUp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) / [tearDown](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown) to prepare the tests
- [asssertEquals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual) and many more assertions

When you use [pytest](http://pytest.org/latest/), you can write tests directly as functions (no need to subclass anything). You can achieve the same set up / tear down pattern by using [fixtures](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#fixture), and write assertions using the [assert statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) since `pytest` features a powerful [assertion introspection](http://pytest.org/latest/assert.html?highlight=introspection#the-writing-and-reporting-of-assertions-in-tests).

[nose](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) also provide [similar features](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#writing-tests) (test functions with a [with_setup](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html?highlight=with_setup#nose.tools.with_setup) decorator).